# IndexError: list index out of range, shooting method

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range

```
x1=np.linspace(xmin, xmax, Nsteps)
y1=np.linspace(0., 0., Nsteps)
h=x1[1]-x1[0]
V1=-V0*np.exp(-alpha*(x1)**2)
E=-1
k=math.sqrt(-2*E)
y1[0]=1
y1[1]=np.exp(k*h)
f=2*[V1-E]

def a():
   for i in range (1,Nsteps):
    denom = np.sum(2+10*h**2*f[i]/12)
    numer = np.sum(1-h**2*f[i+1]/12)   
    return denom/numer


def b():
  for i in range(1, Nsteps):
    denom = np.sum(1-h**2*f[i-1]/12)
    numer = np.sum(1-h**2*f[i+1]/12)
    return denom/numer

def y2():
    a[i]*y1[i] + b[i]*y1[i-1]

for i in range (1, Nsteps):
    print(y2)

plt.plot(x1, y2)
plt.show()
```

For some given parameters, my goal is to produce a code that implements the shooting method. However, when running it i get the IndexError due to different lengths of x1 and y2. My boundaries for *i* are 1 and 1001. I assume that at the boundaries f[i-1] and f[i+1] produce values that are out of the defined range? Also when running the last for-loop, am I running the previous for-loops again within that for-loop and therefore creating something strange? Those are my guesses, and my second question would be if there is a trick for solving that issue? Can I implement some if-condition to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code, first and foremost of which is readability. This isn't the 70s where bytes are expensive - add whitespace to your statements so you can see what's going on. In that same vein, name your variables and functions appropriately. How is a reader supposed to know what `a()` does? As an example, turn this:

```
V1=-V0*np.exp(-alpha*(x1)**2)
```

into this:

```
V1 = -V0 * np.exp(-alpha * (x1**2))
```

It's much easier to see what's going on.

Next, use 4 spaces for indentation, and use it consistently - you can see potential indentation issues much more easily - such as the fact that in `a()` and `b()` you have `return` *inside* the `for` loop, causing it to only run once. All good programming editors (that is, pretty much everything besides Windows Notepad) allow you to set what is inserted when you hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Mixing tabs and spaces is an error in Python 3, so just don't use tab characters (`\t`) at all.

In `y2()`, `a[i]` and `b[i]` don't make sense because `a` and `b` are functions, which cannot be sliced like that, and `i` is not defined in this context.

`print(y2)` will print something like `<function y2 at 0x7fae9e8e3378>`, which I'm pretty sure is not what you want to do. Similarly, `plt.plot(x1, y2)` will not do what you want. If you refactor `y2()` to actually return something (it doesn't currently) and that something is either a list or a NumPy array corresponding to the contents of `x1`, then you should use `plt.plot(x1, y2())` instead.

Put all this into practice, and you'll still have to refactor (and rename) `a()` and `b()` so that they calculate and return the value(s) you want them to. Remember that while functions can read variables defined in the same scope the function is defined in, it is a much better idea to *explicitly* pass the objects you want the function to work on via arguments. So, instead of:

```
some_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
some_str = "abcde"

def zippem():
    return list(zip(some_lst, some_str))
```

You should use:

```
some_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
some_str = "abcde"

def zippem(input_a, input_b):
    return list(zip(input_a, input_b))
```

then call it like so:

```
list_o_tuples = zippem(some_lst, some_str)
```

This allows you to move the function definition to a different module, put it in a class, or just function with arbitrary input instead of the defined objects in its scope.